# Swift: Enable iOS11 large title navigation bar

Tags: xcode, ios11

How can I enable an ios11 large title navigation bar? This is not working.

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Comment: Set the leading, top & trailing constraint of navigation bar to superview

Comment: @JD. how do you do that ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Select ViewController
2. Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller
3. Select NavigationController, select navigation bar
4. Tick "Prefers Large titles" from attributes inspector

[image]

Comment: What if I dont want to put my MyViewController inside a UINavigationController ? I just want a NavBar that has the LargeTitle Style. What he did is dragged a NavBar from the Controls, probably to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.title = "Your title"
    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
    }
```

Please note that if you want to test this out you need at least:

- Xcode 9.0,
- Mac OSX - 10.12.6 or later,
- iPhone/iPad or Xcode 9 simulator with iOS 11.

Comment: That's because the above is assuming your ViewController is inside a UINavigationController, and is not. You dragged a custom NavBar into your ViewController. You are making a custom NavBar that is just a UIView. for some reason the IB ignores the checkbox for largeTitles

Answer (score -2):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }
}
```

Comment: He is draggin and dropping a NavBar into his ViewController (not a UINavigationController). So what you posted is not going to work.